# Disk query in Log Analytics on Azure

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-log-analytics

I was wondering if I could get some help with Log analytics. New to this so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a query that will provide informtaion on disk utilisation in Azure. I've gottwo commands (below), however I'm not able to merge them as I would like one query which gives me % free space, overall size of disk, name of vm and name of disk. Anything else I can get in terms of disk usage would be great, not overly concerned with IOPs at the moment.

The commands are:

This command below proivides info on free space:

```
search ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space"
```

This command below provides information on free Mb remaining.

```
search ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
```

I have tried this which helps, but again information is quite limited

```
search ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes" and TimeGenerated > ago(1d) 
| summarize FreeSpace = min(CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName
| where strlen(InstanceName) ==2 and InstanceName contains ":"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you try this `Perf | where (ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes") | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer | sort by TimeGenerated desc`. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-search-reference#next-steps). Hi, check comments.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT  thanks .. worked perfectly :) I tried using the same for iops, but didn’t work, I’ve got a question open on here, could you see where I’m going wrong please .. thanks again

Comment: `I tried using the same for iops` I will test in my lab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below script to query the Azure log database:

```
// % Disk free space
Perf | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" and InstanceName != "_Total"
| summarize CounterValue = min(CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, CounterName
| order by CounterValue asc nulls first
```

To limit output to disks with less than 20% free space just add an extra condition:

```
| where CounterValue < 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command

```
Perf | where (ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes") | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer | sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

More information about this you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-search-reference).